# Netlogo: "foreach" command with two lists

Tags: netlogo

I have a complete directed graph with each link a weight of it's own. I've managed to select the max-out-link of every turtle. But, sometimes the max-out-link of two turtles are opposite of each other resulting in both links opposite of one another being selected. if this happens i want the link with the lower value to die.
i have created the two lists with this:

```
set max-end1  [[end1] of max-one-of my-out-links [trust]] of turtles
set max-end2  [[end2] of max-one-of my-out-links [trust]] of turtles
```

and by setting an x and y parameter like so:

```
ask turtles
[
set x max-one-of my-out-links [label]
set y my-in-links
]
```

i was hoping to compare each item of the two lists like so:

```
if [x] of max-end2 = any? [y] of max-end1
[
ifelse x X y
[ask x [die]]
[ask y [die]]
]
```

but i have no idea how to combine the foreach command with the if command
can someone help me?

Comment: I see you have previously received an answer using lists at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62451182/deleting-the-opposite-of-a-link-in-a-list-in-netlogo. I did a link-set answer instead. If neither of these answers solve your problem, you will need to explain why or the question will be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: I will remember that for future questions
thank you

Answer (score 2):

I can't actually figure out how your code is supposed to work. Lists seems like an awkward way to approach this and the way you are using `any?` is not going to work. So, I have instead started again and written a standalone model (put it in an empty NetLogo session) to do what I think you are trying to do.

```
links-own [ weight ]

to testme
  clear-all
  create-turtles 15
  ask turtles
  [ create-links-to other turtles
    [ set weight random 100
    ]
  ]
  layout-circle turtles 10
  kill-lowers
end

to kill-lowers
  ; first remove any that's not a max weight
  ask turtles
  [ let big-link max-one-of my-out-links [weight]
    let dying my-out-links with [not member? self (link-set big-link)]
    ask dying [die]
  ]
  ; find pairs and make lower turn red
  ask links
  [ let opp-links links with [end1 = [end2] of myself and end2 = [end1] of myself ]
    if any? opp-links
    [ ask opp-links [set color red]
    ]
  ]
end
```

The testme procedure just creates a complete network. It then calls the kill-lowers procedure to do the link removal. The first section has each turtle identify its `out-link` with the largest weight (or randomly selects one if two equally high) and then creates the `link-set` of all the other links and gets them to die. I think you already have that happening in your code.

So the interesting bit is the section that starts `ask links`. It randomly runs through all the links (think of it as a `foreach` except operating on a set of links rather than a list). In turn, for the particular link, the code checks if there is a link in the opposite direction and sets that to the variable named opp-links. The way it checks is to simply see if there is a link that has `end2` to be its own `end1` and also the other way.  `end1` is the source of a directed link and `end2` is the target.

If there is such a link, it becomes red. That's so you can check the code is doing what you want. After you have tested it, then you have it `die` instead.

Comment: thank you. i used the links section and it works. But can you help me in making the links section execute step by step, i mean only each time the link-set of the maximum out-links changes ?

Comment: I don't understand the question. How would your links change? The way you asked the question says you create a network. If you have links change during the simulation (for example, if they get created for some reason), then the link creation is where you need to check whether it should be created and some other link die.

Comment: Let me apologize. I'm not expressing myself well.
This is the problem: every time i select the max-out-link of turtles and put them in a list (max-links) i'm also iterating the list (in descending order) and asking  end1 to delete all other out-links and end2 to delete all other in-links (that are not maximum). Now before deletion i sometimes come across something like this in my max-links
[(link 5 0) (link 0 4) (link 2 4) (link 3 1) (link 1 2) (link 4 2)]
here I have both [2 4] and [4 2] 
i want the link with the lower value to die and the list updated before i continue with the deletion

Comment: Once you have created your network and deleted all the non-maximum links, each node has either 0 or 1 out-links left. So your list of max-links appears to be pointless - it is ALL the links unless somewhere in your code you create some new link.