# how to delete the lower of two links in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I have a complete directed weighted graph. i have extracted all the max-out-links of all turtles and put them in a descending list.
although sometimes this happens for a list:

> max-links = [(link 4 2) (link 2 1) (link 0 5) (link 3 2) (link 1 2)
> (link 5 3)]

link [2 1] and [1 2] appear in the list and i want the link with the lower value to die and the list to update.
now i have written this code but nothing happens

```
      ask turtles
  [
    set x max-one-of my-out-links [trust]
      set y  one-of my-in-links
  ]
  set max-links sort-on [(- label)] link-set [max-one-of my-out-links [label]] of turtles
  ask item counter max-links
  [
    if [x] of end2 =  [y] of end1
    [
      ifelse [x] of end1 < [x] of end2
      [ask [x] of end1 [die]]
      [ask [x] of end2 [die]]
    ]
    set counter counter + 1
  ]
    set max-links-update sort-on [(- label)] link-set [max-one-of my-out-links [label]] of turtles
```

my goal was to ask the end2 of every turtle and see if the max-out-link of that end2 is the same as one of the in-links of it's first end if so, that means two link has been established between the same two turtles. i think the problem is that when i call upon end2 or end1 for x or y the code doesn't understand that this end2 and end1 belong to the items of the list
can someone tell me how to fix this?
thanks

Comment: You have now asked this or a similar question about 4 times.  Please try to understand the previous answers and then explain why that answer is not doing what you want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Netlogo: "foreach" command with two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62678523/netlogo-foreach-command-with-two-lists)

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity and quicker answers it would be helpful if you could provide a [Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In this case I'm using this toy code that generates a simple network of 4 nodes:

```
links-own [ value ]

to setup
  ca
  random-seed 1
  foreach ( range 0 360 90 ) [ angle ->
    create-turtles 1 [
      set heading angle 
      fd 8
    ]
  ]
  ask turtles [
    create-links-to n-of 2 other turtles [
      set value random-float 1
      set label precision value 3
    ]
  ]
  reset-ticks
end
```

This creates a network with four "duplicate" links- link values are labeled:

[image]

Next, some code that:

- Pulls all end pairs
- Filters so that only duplicated end pairs are processed
- Iterates over duplicated unique pairs and removes the lower-value link

> 

```
to link-filter
  ; Get each link's end pairs
  let endPairs map [ i -> sort [ both-ends ] of i ] sort links

  ; Filter for end pairs that occur more than once
  let duplicatedEnds  ( map [ i -> filter [ j -> j = i ] endPairs ] endPairs )

  ; Keep only unique values
  let uniquePairs reduce sentence map remove-duplicates filter [ k -> length k > 1 ] duplicatedEnds

  ; Iterate over each unique pair
  foreach uniquePairs [ pair ->
    ; Filter for links with those ends, sorted by value
    let matchingLinks filter [ i -> sort [ both-ends ] of i = pair ] sort-on [value] links
    print matchingLinks

    ; Drop the first of the matching links as it is the lower value
    ; if its complement has not already been removed
    if length matchingLinks > 1 [
      ask first matchingLinks [ die ]
    ]
  ]
end
```

After this is run, you can see that the lower-value links are removed:

[image]