# Netlogo: Dealing with a misbehaving arithmetic operator "<"

Tags: netlogo

I have an "ifelse" command like this:

```
    ifelse [label] of [x] of end1 < [label] of [x] of end2
    [ask [x] of end1 [hide-link]]
    [ask [x] of end2 [hide-link]]
```

x is defined as such:

```
 set x max-one-of my-out-links [label]
```

The purpose of this code is: Out of two opposite links, have the link with the lower value hidden. But, no matter the changes I make to the operator (change it to ">") in proportionate to changes I also make to end1 and end2 to keep the same logic, it always hides the link with higher value.
This is the entire code in the event that the problem isn't in the code provided above.

```
 ask turtles
  [
      set x max-one-of my-out-links [trust]
      set y one-of my-in-links
  ]
    ask links
      [
      set test1  [[x] of end1] of self
      set test2  [[y] of end2] of self
      ]
    set max-links sort-on [(- label)] link-set [max-one-of my-out-links [label]] of turtles
      foreach max-links
      [
        the-links -> ask the-links
        [
          if  [[who] of end1 ] of test1 = [[who] of end2] of test2
              and [[who] of end2] of test1 = [[who] of end1] of test2
          [
            ifelse [trust] of [x] of end1 < [trust] of [x] of end2
            [ask [x] of end1 [hide-link]]
            [ask [x] of end2 [hide-link]]
          ]
        ]
      ]
```

Thank you.

Comment: This is question 10 asking the same thing in different ways. You don't need lists. You definitely don't need `who` (it is almost always an error to use `who` in NetLogo). You are incredibly confused with your constructions - x and y are just more layers of mess. Stop asking the same question over and over and over. Instead, understand the answers you have been given. If they are not doing what you want, then explain what you are trying to do and what is wrong with the answer. Have a look at the answer to your first question, which deletes all the non-maximum links. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: This is a different matter. I realize my code is messy but this is the first project i'm writing in Netogo and regardless of how messy it is, it's functioning without errors. I cannot explain my entire algorithm because it's of my own creation and has been proven right and I don't want it on the internet. Regardless of whether this is for the same project or not, now, I just want to know why the "<" operator isn't doing what it's supposed to do. Also, the answer you're referring me to was helpful but does not solve getting for example link 2-3 and link 3-2 as results. I'm trying to solve this.

Comment: The "<" IS doing what it's supposed to do. The problem is that `[trust] of [x] of end1` and `[trust] of [x] of end2` are not doing what you think they're doing. Print them out before doing the "<" and see what they look like. That's my point, you have introduced layers of errors and you're ignoring everyone when we try and help you fix those errors. This is not a different matter - it's exactly the same error with different symptoms because you haven't fixed the underlying problem yet.

Comment: yes. I printed them out and realized the problem. Can you please help me fix the problem of getting two opposite links as final results? because the first code that you were kind enough to provide doesn't solve this part and the last couple of questions were to try and solve this part. Or if I'm wrong at least show me in the first code where the opposite links problem is addressed?

Comment: Pointed you to the wrong version of your question, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62678523/netlogo-foreach-command-with-two-lists/62683120#62683120